# How to find the right files to edit the css code in custom wordpress theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a custom-made WordPress theme-based website. The problem is I'm not being able to change the dimensions/size of the images in my blog section. No matter what size I change, using the WordPress dashboard it stays in the same size. I have attached the image below.

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqVjm.png)

I tried using the inspect tool to see what is overriding the inline CSS I apply, I got to know that there is a max-width mentioned in a file that is causing this problem.

But I don't know how to locate this file and remove the code, so the image changes according to the specified size.

I have attached the image of the inspect tool results below
[Inspect tool result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmyVU.png)

I tried searching for the file which the inspect tool mentions but the file it points to is the index (HTML) file of the blog post. But I couldn't find this Html file in my theme contents and moreover, all the files are in PHP in WordPress.

It would be truly helpful if someone can assist me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can solve your problem by modifying the style.css file that is present in your theme.
You can find it in settings-> theme editor-> style.css

if you write some properties there using your tag class it should read your changes and if it doesn't work use !important next to the css property

I hope I was helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the code in the additional CSS section while browsing as per you said.